# Will Android be able to handle a single large activity like this?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Android soundboard. I currently have 12 pages for this specific category. Each page has its own activity and each page as 10 buttons.

Someone asked me today why I don't just use one activity and switch the setcontentview (XML) between the pages rather then having so many activities.

I thought about it and it doesn't seem like a bad idea. But I'm curious on if it really would be better.

This means that this one activity would have a 100+ switch case statement for its onclick and onlongclick methods. It would have over 200 variables. I would have to add over 200 listeners (although I think i could set the 10 listeners as I load the specific page rather than all at the beginning. I could also release the current ones before the new XML is displayed).

Will Android be able to handle a single activity like this? I plan on adding more sounds so maybe one day I might have 20 pages or so.

Comment: If you have to have a 100+ switch statement, something is seriously wrong with your app. I'll post an answer with a better way to do this.

Comment: If they're all that similar, just start a new instance of that `Activity` and pass in whatever information distinguishes them through a `Bundle` passed with the `Intent`.

Comment: It would be a 100+ switch case because it would need a case for every button id. 10 buttons at 12 pages is 120. Not counting any more i add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, make it all one activity. Different `Activities` should only really be used for completely different use cases.  Consider using a `ListView` or a `GridView`, or a 'ViewPager` inside of one Activity.

If you do end up using a `ListView` or anything that takes an Adapter, your Activity should look like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

 int mySounds[] = {R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2}; //etc. could also be a 2d array, one for each page of sounds.

 protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
 {
   setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myactivity_listView);

   lv.setAdapter(new SoundAdapter(this));

 }

class SoundAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  Context cont;
  SoundAdapter(Context c){
   this.cont = c;
  }

  getView(int id, View convertView){
   if(convertView == null){
     ...
     //inflate view to be a row/gridcell
   }

   convertView.setOnClickListener(new SoundClickListener(mySounds[id]));
  }



}

 class SoundClickListener extends View.OnClickListener{

   int resId;

   public SoundClickListener(int resId)
   {
     this.resId = resId;
   }

   protected void onClick(View v){
     playSoundWithId(resId);
   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll address a few of your points individually:

- Will android be able to handle it. Yes. Nevertheless, you should be smart about the way you design things.
- Depending on the version you're running, you should look into either `TabActivity` or `Fragment`s. If you build your activity out of these, you can base which ten or so `Button`s have listeners on them at any given time.
- Here's an even more radical idea: create a mother class that extends `Activity` and pass its constructor information on which buttons to display. This way, you have only 10 buttons or so in an `Activity`, but you have 12 activities.
- Even more radical idea: extend button and put it as an inner class of your extension of `Activity`. This could lead you some interesting places.

If you ask a *slightly* better question, I could give you a better answer, but here's some ideas, run with it. Good luck.